# Commas instead of newline express nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

When i generate a project using express it throw commas instead of newlines

example:
    express my_project

generate this in a single line

```
,/**, * Module dependencies., */,,var express = require('express'),  , routes =      require('./routes'),  , user = require('./routes/user'),  , http = require('http'),  , path = require('path');,,var app = express();,,
```

instead of

```
/**
* Module dependencies. 
*/
var express = require('express'),  
routes = require('./routes'), 
user = require('./routes/user'), 
http = require('http'), 
path = require('path');

var app = express();
```

every file generated by express has the same format

How i prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: this could be a bug in express...what OS are you on, and what is the version of express?

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 13.04 and this kind of behavior makes me seriously concerned about using Express for anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you check inside the [build file](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/bin/express) you have:

```
var eol = os.EOL
```

You then have:

```
    var app = [
        ''
      , '/**'
      , ' * Module dependencies.'
      , ' */'
      , ''
      , 'var express = require(\'express\')'
      , '  , routes = require(\'./routes\')'
      , '  , user = require(\'./routes/user\')'
        ...
        ...
        ].join(eol);
```

That's what being written into app.js.

If this doesn't work for you try replacing that with what express previously had:

```
var eol = 'win32' == os.platform() ? '\r\n' : '\n'
```

Comment: You should consider reporting the issue as well

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Express 3.1.0 worked and then 3.1.1 and every subsequent Express version is broken.

But this turned out to be a bug in the Node.js for Windows build that was fixed in a very recent version of Node.js. Uninstall Node.js, navigate to http://nodejs.org/, and click on Install to download the latest installer.